# Alteração dinâmica em um elemento ao redimensionar a janela

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heightJanela = $(window).height() + "px";
    $("#banner-hold").css("height",heightJanela);
});
```

Realizei o código acima, para que quando o documento for carregado, a `div` "banner-hold" recebe o `height` igual ao da janela. Para que a mesma função fosse realizada no momento que a janela recebesse um `resize`, troquei o `.ready` por `.resize` e `.change` porém nenhum dos dois funcionou, como posso corrigir isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).resize` não funcionará por que não é o documento que muda de tamanho e sim a janela, o correto seria `$(window).resize`. Para executar o código ao carregar e ao modificar tamanho recomendo o seguinte método: 
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mudarTamanho();
    $( window ).resize(mudarTamanho);
});

function mudarTamanho(){
    var heightJanela = $(window).height() + "px";
    $("#banner-hold").css("height", heightJanela);
}
```

[Documentação do resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) (https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Pode haver um pouco de espaço passando/sobrando, devido a margin e padding, caso queira remove-lo adicione essa regra ao seu CSS:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: perfeito, exatamente o que eu estava procurando :D